# Convert my dictionary keys from tuples to the elements inside the tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

My dictionary has tuples as keys, and the tuples have only one element each. For each key in the dictionary I need to convert it to the string value inside the tuple.

I have tried the following code:
I used key[0] because every key is a tuple of length 1.

```
for key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key[0]] = dictionary.pop(key)
dictionary
```

The code above gives the following error: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during itera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your dictionary over like so:

```
dict_copy = {key[0]: value for key, value in dictionary.items()}
```

This is a dictionary comprehension, equivalent to doing

```
dict_copy = dict() # or {}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    dict_copy[key[0]] = dictionary[key]
```

Comment: You don’t need a new dictionary name in the list comprehension statement